Use go/analysis to obtain the function invocation graph in the self-developed project
I want to get the function call graph information in a self-developed Go language project through the "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis" tool, the following is the code obtained, but when it runs, pass. There is only one main.go file in the root directory in Files, I don't know what causes it? I want to get the function call graph information in a self-developed Go language project through the "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis" tool, the following is the code obtained, but when it runs, pass. There is only one main.go file in the root directory in Files, I don't know what causes it?Please advise
var Analyzer = &analysis.Analyzer{
    Name: "functionCallGraph",
    Doc:  "Generates a call graph with function details",
    Run:  run,
    Requires: []*analysis.Analyzer{
        inspect.Analyzer, // 添加依赖分析器
    },
    FactTypes:        []analysis.Fact{},
    RunDespiteErrors: true,
    //Requires:  []*analysis.Analyzer{config.Analyzer, accumulation.Analyzer},
}

type FunctionInfo struct {
    Name       string
    FilePath   string
    Line       int
    Parameters []string
    Returns    []string
    Calls      []CallInfo
}

type CallInfo struct {
    TargetName    string
    TargetPackage string
    TargetVersion string
    TargetFile    string
    TargetLine    int
}

func run(pass *analysis.Pass) (interface{}, error) {
    inspect := pass.ResultOf[inspect.Analyzer].(*inspector.Inspector)

    //inspect := getInspector()
    funcInfos := []FunctionInfo{}
    nodeFilter := []ast.Node{
        (*ast.FuncDecl)(nil),
        (*ast.CallExpr)(nil),
    }

    // Map to store function info by name
    funcMap := map[string]*FunctionInfo{}

    inspect.Preorder(nodeFilter, func(node ast.Node) {
        switch n := node.(type) {
        case *ast.FuncDecl:
            // Process function declarations
            pos := pass.Fset.Position(n.Pos())
            funcInfo := FunctionInfo{
                Name:       n.Name.Name,
                FilePath:   pos.Filename,
                Line:       pos.Line,
                Parameters: getParameters(pass.TypesInfo, n),
                Returns:    getReturns(pass.TypesInfo, n),
            }
            funcInfos = append(funcInfos, funcInfo)
            funcMap[funcInfo.Name] = &funcInfo

        case *ast.CallExpr:
            // Process function calls
            //pos := pass.Fset.Position(n.Pos())
            if callerFunc := findEnclosingFunc(pass, n.Pos()); callerFunc != nil {
                callInfo := processCallExpr(pass, n)
                if callInfo != nil {
                    funcMap[callerFunc.Name].Calls = append(funcMap[callerFunc.Name].Calls, *callInfo)
                }
            }
        }
    })

    // Print results
    for _, info := range funcInfos {
        fmt.Printf("Function %s at %s:%d\n", info.Name, info.FilePath, info.Line)
        fmt.Printf("  Parameters:\n")
        for _, param := range info.Parameters {
            fmt.Printf("    - %s\n", param)
        }
        fmt.Printf("  Returns:\n")
        for _, ret := range info.Returns {
            fmt.Printf("    - %s\n", ret)
        }
        fmt.Printf("  Calls:\n")
        for _, call := range info.Calls {
            fmt.Printf("    -> %s (Package: %s, File: %s:%d)\n",
                call.TargetName, call.TargetPackage, call.TargetFile, call.TargetLine)
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }

    return nil, nil
}

func main() {
    err := os.Chdir(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("not find : %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    singlechecker.Main(Analyzer)

}


